# H-parameters of a BJT Transistor Amplifier

Tags: transistors, bjt

H-parameters of a two port network containing passive elements can be found easily. For example "output short circuited input impedance" of the network is obtained by short circuiting the output terminal and then calculating the total impedance of the network. Can we apply the same rules (we use to find H-parameters  in a circuit with passive elements only) to find the H-parameters of a two port network with a BJT in it ? OR there is another way to find the H-parameters of such network ?

Comment: Because the h-parameter method is commonly used for describing the properties of a BJT, you are - of course - allowed to apply this method for decribing an active two-port containing a BJT.

Comment: thanks. can you please provide me a link where i can see this method of finding h parameters in case of bjt ?

Comment: Why do you want a link? There is nothing else required than the definition of the 4 parameters (which is known to you). But the question arises: For which purpose do you need the h-parameters for an amplifier stage (for example)?